# Automation vs performance testing

Tags: performance-testing, automation-testing

I am a beginner in performance testing and I would like to ask, with automation testing is it possible to be transformed into performance testing?

For example, I have the code of an automation of the login scenario for X users, will it be a good practice if I use the statistics of the code run to represent it as a performance diagram?

Comment: This is not currently a programming question as defined in the [help] pages. You might try asking on sqa.stackexchange.com , but please read their help pages to make sure that your question is on-topic there. Also, I think you would need to explain your question in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up to certain extent yes, you will get response time and may be some relationship between the number of users and response time, however there are some constraints as well:

1. Most probably you won't get all the metrics and [KPIs](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-kpis-part-1-what-are-kpis) you can get with the protocol-level-based-tools
2. Browsers are **very** resource intensive, i.e. [Firefox 94 system requirements](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/94.0.1/system-requirements/) are at least 1 CPU core and 2 GB of RAM per browser instance

So I would rather think not about re-using existing automation tests for checking the performance, but rather converting them into a performance test script to get better results and less resource footprint